# Go to a specefic line (row) in spyder's variable explorer

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

Is it possible to go into a specific line (row) in spyder's variable explorer?

Let's say I have a variable named `my_list` containing a list of integers, how can I go and see what the `nth` item is in `my_list` using variable explorer?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to go to a specific row in a list, Numpy array or dataframe at the moment. You have to browse manually to the position you want to inspect.

Comment: Thanks for the response ;)

Comment: No problem, glad you found it useful!

Comment: I hope you consider implementing such a feature... it's really useful and come in handy.

Comment: The problem is we load data on demand, i.e. if you have 300.000 rows, we only load the first 500 rows and load the rest as users browse the list. In any case, if you want a particular row, you can always do `li[10000]` (for instance).